# Theorem of column space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

> 1. Recall that the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^m$ iff the equation
>      $Ax=b$ has a solution for each $b$. We can restate this fact as
>      follows:
> 2. The column space of an $m \times  n$ matrix $A$ is all of
>      $\mathbb{R}^m$ if and only if the equation $Ax = b$ has a solution for
>      each $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Would the meaning be changed if the "in $\mathbb{R}^m$" was removed in the definition for column space? I'm unsure of why that addition is necessary in the definition, since it wasn't needed in the definition before it.

Comment: What definitions are you referring to? You haven't stated any definition.

Comment: Labeled them 1 and 2 now. Sorry if the terminology is incorrect. I basically mean the first statement and the second statement

Comment: Statement 1 should say "for each $b$ in $\mathbb R^m$", because otherwise we don't know what $b$ is without guessing. (But, the most important thing is just to be clear.)

Comment: Thanks! That was my confusion, why it seemed like one statement had for each $b$ in $\mathbb{R^m}$ and the other didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning here: "for each $b$" in statement (1) and "for each $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$" in statement (2) mean the same thing.  Really both of them should say "for each $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$", since taken literally "for each $b$" means for every $b$ no matter what kind of object $b$ is.  But this is obviously silly, and in context it is usually fine to say just "for each $b$" meaning "for each $b$ for which the statement would even make sense".